# hasListeners becomes false when the app is launched through app shortcuts or Siri

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, siri, sirishortcuts

I am trying to integrate App Intents and shortcuts in my react native app and I want to send an event from iOS native modules to my react native code.
I am doing this using bridging
I have listened for the event that is being sent by iOS native modules named as **sendMoneyEvent** . Now, it works fine when app is launched through app icon. But, my event listeners code does not seems to work when my app is launched through shortcuts or Siri.
Here is my listener in my App.tsx

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Listen for the event
    const { SendMoneyModule } = NativeModules;
    const emit = new NativeEventEmitter(SendMoneyModule);
    const eventListener = emit.addListener("SendMoneyEvent", event => {
      console.error("Event reminder received:", event.name);
      // Handle the event data as needed
    });
    return () => {
      eventListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Here is my Native module

```
//  RCTCalemdarModule.m
//  Calendar
//
//  Created by ReactNativeDev on 20/11/2023.
//
// RCTCalendarModule.m
#import "RCTSendMoneyModule.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
@implementation RCTSendMoneyModule

// To export a module named RCTCalendarModule
// To export a module named CalendarModuleFoo

{
  bool hasListeners;
}

// Will be called when this module's first listener is added.
-(void)startObserving {
    hasListeners = YES;
    // Set up any upstream listeners or background tasks as necessary
}

// Will be called when this module's last listener is removed, or on dealloc.
-(void)stopObserving {
    hasListeners = NO;
    // Remove upstream listeners, stop unnecessary background tasks
}



RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
// method to declare supported events
- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
  return @[@"SendMoneyEvent"];
}
// RCTCalendarModule.m
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(createCalendarEventFromSwift)
{
    [self createCalendarEvent:@"DefaultName" location:@"DefaultLocation"];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(createCalendarEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  RCTLogWarn(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
  
  if(hasListeners)
  {
    NSDictionary *eventData = @{@"name": name};
    [self sendEventWithName:@"SendMoneyEvent" body:eventData];  }
  
}

 @end
```

Now sendEventWithName method send events to react native code and works very well when I call the createCalendarEvent from my app.tsx but it does not works when I launch my app through shortcuts or Siri. I think that useEffect is not rendering at all.